# How to read and write to a file using multithreading scraping process in Python? Getting Windows Error 32

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the links using parameter from a text file and writing the result to the csv file. But when i try to implement it with multithreding , I get the error::

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by   another process:    
'c:\\users\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpqseulj.webdriver.xpi\\components\\wdIStatus.xpt'
```

Please help in resolving the issue.
Inline is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re
from threading import Thread
import urlparse
import urllib2
import sys;
import csv
import operator
reload(sys);
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")


with open("C:\\Test2.csv", "w") as f:
     fieldnames = ("SearchQuery", "Title")
     output = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
     output.writerow(fieldnames)


def th(ur):    
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q="+ur)
    time.sleep(20);

    html_source = driver.page_source

    regex = '<span class="label">(.*?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)

   Cluster = re.findall(pattern, html_source)
   Cluster = [H.replace("All Topics","") for H in Cluster]
   Cluster = [H.replace("Other topics","") for H in Cluster]
   Cluster = filter(operator.methodcaller('strip'), Cluster)

   print ur, str(Cluster)

   output.writerow([ur, HotelName]) 
   driver.close();


Symbolfile = open("Result.txt")
Symbollist = Symbolfile.read()
new = Symbollist.split("\n")


threadlist = []

for u in new:                               # thread implementation
    t = Thread(target=th, args=(u,))
    t.start()
    threadlist.append(t)

for b in threadlist:
    b.join()
```

Comment: I removed quote from `driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q="+ur")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use locks if multiple threads will be writing to the same file.

This looks like a reasonable example: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-threads-synchronization-locks-rlocks-semaphores-conditions-events-and-queues/

"Print" is also not thread safe.

Comment: As an afterthought, you could cheat and use the standard logging module to write your output? (Just set it up in such a way that you can re-name it and use it as a CSV) The logging module is thread safe so would take care of all the locking for you ...

Comment: Not sure how to add itor it will be the optimal solution

Comment: It's pretty simple. Standard Python module. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html